# NeoVim indents each property:value in CSS

Tags: indentation, filetype-html

I have a style element in an HTML file. When I type, NeoVim continuously indents each successive line:

[image: bad indentation]

In my Vim, it works correctly:

[image: correct indentation]

My [vimrc](https://github.com/zoliky/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc).

I would be grateful for any suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Neovim v0.3.1 with a minimal `filetype plugin indent on` setup. What does `:set inde? ai? si?` give you? Do you possibly have a plugin installed with its own indent file for CSS? You can check with: `:filter /indent/ scriptnames`.

Comment: Strange. I loaded neovim with a minimal "filetype plugin indent" and still have the same issue. I'm using version v0.3.1 as well.

Comment: My brain got stuck on "css" and tested with a **css** file and not an **html** file as in your example. I can reproduce this behavior with `nvim -u NONE -c ':filetype plugin indent on | :e test.html'`. `HtmlIndent()` is definitely the cause.

Comment: For the record, I get the same indenting behavior in Vim 8 as well.

Comment: @Zero, I've restored the note from OP about it working in Vim. It's not usually a good idea to just remove stuff like that in edits unless OP has confirmed somehow they were incorrect.

Comment: @paxdiablo Okay, sorry about that. I'm still getting used to how much is okay to edit; I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

This particular issue seems to have come up more than once:

- [A 2009 Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912132/messy-css-indentation-in-vim)*
- [A post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/8ptng4/broken_css_indenting_inside_stylestyle_tags_in_vim/) in [the Vim subreddit](https://reddit.com/r/vim) from just a few months ago

Unfortunately the replies and answers mostly consist of non-solutions (suggesting to turn off `filetype` entirely) or workarounds (`set indentkeys+=;`). After a lot of digging, I gained more useful knowledge.

#### Quick History

The current `indent/html.vim` that ships with the (Neo)Vim runtime is a fork of [Andy Wokula's indent file](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2075). This fork was [originally created and is currently maintained by Bram himself](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/8bb1c3e53ef0ee259cfa5f9b3a3a91ec1fa90fb0#diff-c5802b9fe6ca7e175ecf7f5f3bea690e) in 2014. **It is this overhaul where this CSS-indentation bug was first introduced;** Andy's original HTML indent file did not have this indentation issue. Ever since then, it has remained.

#### ...Until very recently!

A [very recent upstream commit](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/fc65cabb15d0236bce001ad78e12a40511caf941#diff-c5802b9fe6ca7e175ecf7f5f3bea690e) (22 days ago from the time of writing) included an update to `indent/html.vim` **that fixes the CSS-indentation**. Adding this upstream version to `~/<vimfiles>/indent` and reproducing the example in your question gives the desired behavior.

## Solution

Add the [`indent/html.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/fc65cabb15d0236bce001ad78e12a40511caf941/runtime/indent/html.vim) from the current Vim upstream to your vimfiles:

- **Neovim**: `~/.config/nvim/indent`
- **Vim**: `~/.vim/indent`

And of course, make sure that `filetype plugin indent on` exists somewhere in your configuration.

---

* This question predates the overhaul fork in 2014, but presents the same symptoms. Perhaps the [2007 version](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/9964e468c0209f6b8286e0b08109817c845a3079/runtime/indent/html.vim) happened to have the same issue?

Comment: Finally a proper answer! I've been banging my head against the wall on this one and all the "solutions" I could find were stupid things like "turn off your indenting and bind this formatter on F8". Are you serious? 
Updating to Vim 8.2 worked, thanks ZeroKnight!